# JavaScript - Clearing an Element

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I have a script which takes an image about to be uploaded and adds an image preview of the image. The only problem is that if the form is filled out again, the previous image does not clear.

The id of the  where thumbnail images are being placed is" thumbnail". Could someone help me add a line or two of code to this that clears the div before adding a new image preview?

```
<script> 
    jQuery(function($){
var fileDiv = document.getElementById("upload");
var fileInput = document.getElementById("upload-image");
console.log(fileInput);
fileInput.addEventListener("change",function(e){
  var files = this.files
  showThumbnail(files);
},false)

fileDiv.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  $(fileInput).show().focus().click().hide();
  e.preventDefault();
},false)

fileDiv.addEventListener("dragenter",function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
},false);

fileDiv.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
},false);

fileDiv.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var dt = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;

  showThumbnail(files);
},false);

function showThumbnail(files){

    // clear the div

  for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
    var file = files[i]
    var imageType = /image.*/
    if(!file.type.match(imageType)){
      console.log("Not an Image");
      continue;
    }

    var image = document.createElement("img");
    // image.classList.add("")
    var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
    image.file = file;
    thumbnail.appendChild(image)

    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (function(aImg){
      return function(e){
        aImg.src = e.target.result;
      };
    }(image))
    var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    image.onload= function(){
      ctx.drawImage(image,100,100)
    }
  }
}
          });
          </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
thumbnail.innerHTML = ''
```

that will clear the thumbnail's contents. afterwards you can append the image just like you're doing in your code.

Edit: you should really use jQuery, to avoid cross-browser headaches:

```
$('#thumbnail').empty();
```

this also clears the thumbnail element, but defers cross-browser issue tackling to jQuery.

Comment: Where should I put this? I added it in right after the //clear the div comment but it broke the image previews altogether

Comment: That second line, the edit, worked perfectly! Thanks!